# Paypal chained Payment Ios MPL Issue

Tags: ios, paypal, chained-payments

Currently ios team is having an issue with chained payment in the app,the server team
needs an order id to be set as tracking id for tracking the payment.But ios team says
that they cant give a tracking id as there is no option to give tracking id in the sdk
mobile payment library.
Ios team says like after every chained payment transaction in the app
it generates a pay key after a succesful transaction and a coorelationId for a failed transaction
But it does not have a tracking id option.
Server team says like they cant implement
an ipn listener to update the db without the tracking id (Order Id).

I have been stuck with this issue for days can someone please help me out on this? It would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

As said by your iOS team

> Paypal MPL you will not get any  ‘tracking id
>   ‘ or some other information which you will get when integrate paypal
>   in the web.
>
> every chained payment transaction in the app it generates a pay key
>   and payment status after a succesful transaction and a coorelationId
>   for a failed transaction

This is correct, i have also faced this issue as it only send paykey no other information

If you want to track for the any id you can send the paykey to the server and from the server they may call the API to get more information and tracking id which you may use,
 
for more information regarding this api refer this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/ , check PaymentDetailsRequest which takes ‘payKey’ as mentioned in the [step 3 in their doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/)

Comment: Hi,thanks for helping me out,through PaymentDetails API i can fetch the transaction details from the PayPal server.But the issue is what to do with ipn listener implemenation?. I was planning to use the tracking id(OrderId) to identify the paypal transaction and perform the necessary DB update.I was planning to implement both paymentdetails api and ipn listener ,in case the first one fails due to some connection failure.Ipn Listener was supposed to be the backup.This is my current scenario.How should i approach this?

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)

Answer (score 0):

I Have managed to resolve the issue.For fetching the adaptive payment details,i am using the PaymentDetails API as mentioned by Pyro above.The only remaining issue was how will i track the transaction in the IPN listener .As of right now to my knowledge,IOS sdk doesn't offer a way to pass tracking Id ,so i exploited the memo field to pass in my id and i am able to retrieve this at my server side.I know this is a hack but am not left with much options.This link guided me to this workaround
[https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/67](http://PayPal%20IOS%20SDK%20Issue)

If anyone knows a better way ,please do share.I hope this helps someone.